# How to issue action when touch in specific coordinates on view android

Tags: android, touch, coordinates, ontouchlistener, avatar

hello everyone I am developing application and I have a girl and boy avatar .. I want to issue action like Alert Dialog if he touch specific coordinates in the avatar how to do that without drawing canvas ??
any help please !!

Comment: Why aren't you using `ImageView` to show girl and boy avatar. Moreover you'll know which avatar is clicked as `ImageView` has `onClickListener`

Comment: Get coordinates from view matrix [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672370/android-i-want-to-get-different-x-y-position-on-touch-when-canvas-scale-and-tran/43673019#43673019)

Comment: @AkshayChordiya I already used ImageView I want to issue event depend on specific coordinates in that imageView , are you the one who voted for not useful question ?

Comment: Nope. Not me. I'm already trying to help you.

Comment: oh , I am sorry . I just  was thinking if my question stupid or something  , apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View YOUR_VIEW = findViewById(R.id.MY_VIEW);
YOUR_VIEW.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("Coordinates:", " X: " + String.valueOf(event.getX()) + " , Y: " + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: but I want to issue action depends on a group of coordinates ?? like if he touch the mouth of the avatar show hem alert !!

Comment: for that, you should have coordinates of the mouth or somewhere else!